# Clicking to Dial Phone Numbers on Websites Using Dialpad.com

Tags: phone, voip

I'm trying to help someone "click to dial" telephone number links that occur on websites.

She is using Ubuntu 22.04, and has a telephone service called [dialpad.com](https://www.dialpad.com/), that will allow her to make calls using her web browser.

On Chromebook, and Windows 10, when she simply clicks a `tel:555-555-5555` link, from a web page, the web browser asks her if she'd like to make the call using diapad.com, and then she's able to immediately initiate the call.

An example of one of these type of links can be seen [here](http://neartalk.com/call/#555-555-5555). And here's what I see when I click one of those links:

[image]

How can I set up the same behavior she's accustom to on Ubuntu 22.04 and Firefox (where simply clicking the phone number dials it at [dialpad.com](https://www.dialpad.com/))?

Comment: On a chrombook, she's not using firefox. What about windows 10? Have you tried using chrome instead of firefox?

Comment: Yeah, she actually uses chromium primarily on Ubuntu right now. On Chromebook, I think she installed a dialpad app, and I think that app was responsible for registering dialpad as something to handle `tel:` links with. In Windows, similarly, I think she installed a dialpad exe that somehow informs the browser of how to handle the tel links. Since dialpad doesn't offer anything for Ubuntu, I'm trying to figure out how to do this manually somehow. @mchid

Comment: There is a [dialpad extension](https://help.dialpad.com/hc/en-us/articles/211463286-Enable-Click-to-Call-with-Chrome) for Chrome. If you need to, you can download Google Chrome for Ubuntu from Google and then install the deb file manually. If firefox downloads it to a snap directory, transfer the deb file to your `~/Downloads` directory and then run the following commands to install: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/filename.deb` where "filename.deb" is the actual name of the downloaded deb file.

Comment: @mchid You've been a great help to us. After installing the [dial pad extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dialpad-extension/mhoeffeimbfbmpccjcodjeeglinbpicp), that the [article](https://help.dialpad.com/hc/en-us/articles/211463286-Enable-Click-to-Call-with-Chrome) you provided links to (in the first paragraph), in Brave Browser we go to the  `☰ > Extensions > Dialpad Extension > Details > Extension Options` and set it to "Web App". After that, when she clicks `tel` links the call gets made via the dialpad.com website. If you formalize your comment to an answer, I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Dialpad extension](https://help.dialpad.com/hc/en-us/articles/211463286-Enable-Click-to-Call-with-Chrome) for Chrome to enable click to call. If you need to, you can download Google Chrome for Ubuntu from Google and then install the deb file manually. If forefox downloads it to a snap directory, transfer the deb file to your `~/Downloads` directory and then run the following commands to install (replacing `filename.deb` with the actual name of the downloaded deb file):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/filename.deb
```

Alternatively, you can use the extension with the Brave browser. Run the following commands to install Brave:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl

sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install brave-browser
```

---

[You can download the extension here.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dialpad-extension/mhoeffeimbfbmpccjcodjeeglinbpicp)

Then from either Brave or Google Chrome, go to:

**Settings** > **Extensions** > **Dialpad Extension** > **Details** > **Extension Options**

Finally, set it to "**Use this Dialpad app to place all calls**" OR set it to "**Web App**"

Comment: As a token of our gratitude, and since you're obviously a cat lover (based on your profile pic), we made you this [video](http://www.lonniebest.com/cats.mp4), which showcases 10,000 cats at 60 cats per second. Enjoy!